gnome-session-flashback crashes when returning from other system KVM
I have a Mac for work and a desktop that runs Ubuntu 24.04. They share a monitor with a built in KVM. I used this same monitor with 22.04 and then upgraded to when it came out earlier this year. Only recently has the Ubuntu system started to crash when I come back from the other system (Mac).
some logs
> journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell

Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Will monitor session c5
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Extension ding@rastersoft.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com>
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Extension tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/til>
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Extension ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extens>
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@u>
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1706053]: Window manager warning: Failed to parse saved session file: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm3/.config/mutter/sessions/10eedb0f3d4dcfb67f1731535238>
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Nov 13 17:00:39 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: no authentication service is enabled, using password authentication
Nov 13 17:00:40 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: Registering session with GDM
Nov 13 17:00:43 taco gnome-shell[1706053]: no authentication service is enabled, using password authentication
Nov 13 17:00:56 taco org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1706053]: XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
Nov 13 17:00:56 taco org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1706053]:       after 4235 requests (4235 known processed) with 1 events remaining.

> journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-flashback
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: Property 'libinput Accel Profiles Available' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: Property 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: Property 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: pam_unix(gnome-flashback:auth): conversation failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: pam_unix(gnome-flashback:auth): auth could not identify password for [billy]
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_get_display: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_get_toplevel: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gdk_window_set_cursor: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:26 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 13 17:00:27 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Property 'libinput Accel Profiles Available' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
Nov 13 17:00:27 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Property 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
Nov 13 17:00:32 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Nov 13 17:00:37 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Nov 13 17:00:37 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Nov 13 17:00:37 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Nov 13 17:00:37 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Nov 13 17:00:37 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Nov 13 17:00:47 taco gnome-flashback[1706798]: Property 'libinput Accel Profiles Available' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
Nov 13 17:00:47 taco gnome-flashback[1706798]: Property 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
Nov 13 17:00:47 taco gnome-flashback[1706798]: Property 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2

gnome-flashback segfaults from kern.log
2024-11-13T17:00:25.448587-05:00 taco kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1731535225.447:6164): pid=2233 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  
bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.11" mask="receive" pid=1692032 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=227
8 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-11-13T17:00:25.448595-05:00 taco kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-11-13T17:00:25.565626-05:00 taco kernel: workqueue: dm_irq_work_func [amdgpu] hogged CPU for >10000us 32 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554639-05:00 taco kernel: gnome-flashback[1518210]: segfault at 5b1cf0729c18 ip 000070435c7ea298 sp 00007fff5511c410 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2409.32[70435c683000+3ae000] likely on CP
U 20 (core 36, socket 0)
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554645-05:00 taco kernel: Code: 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 49 89 f4 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 e8 14 c6 ff ff 48 85 db 0f 84 93 00 00 00 48 89 c6 <48> 8b 03 48 85 c0 74 05
 48 39 30 74 0c 48 89 df e8 b3 76 ea ff 85
2024-11-13T17:00:27.641597-05:00 taco kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1731535227.639:6165): pid=2233 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  
bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.11" mask="receive" pid=1692032 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=227
8 peer_label="unconfined"

syslog
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554432-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_get_display: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554448-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_get_toplevel: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554459-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554470-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554482-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gdk_window_set_cursor: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554493-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554639-05:00 taco kernel: gnome-flashback[1518210]: segfault at 5b1cf0729c18 ip 000070435c7ea298 sp 00007fff5511c410 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2409.32[70435c683000+3ae000] likely on CPU 20 (core 36, socket 0)
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554645-05:00 taco kernel: Code: 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 49 89 f4 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 08 e8 14 c6 ff ff 48 85 db 0f 84 93 00 00 00 48 89 c6 <48> 8b 03 48 85 c0 74 05 48 39 30 74 0c 48 89 df e8 b3 76 ea ff 85
2024-11-13T17:00:27.641597-05:00 taco kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1731535227.639:6165): pid=2233 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.11" mask="receive" pid=1692032 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=2278 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-11-13T17:00:27.641604-05:00 taco kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-11-13T17:00:26.554516-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1518210]: message repeated 2 times: [ gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed]
2024-11-13T17:00:27.643943-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: gnome-flashback.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644001-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: gnome-flashback.service: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/gnome-flashback.service, ignoring: Invalid argument
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644016-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: gnome-flashback.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644032-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: gnome-flashback.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644046-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: gnome-flashback.service: Consumed 36.347s CPU time, 200.2M memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644240-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: gnome-flashback.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644255-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Stopped target gnome-flashback.target - GNOME Flashback.
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644277-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Stopping gnome-flashback.target - GNOME Flashback...
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644293-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Stopped target gnome-session-x11@gnome-flashback-metacity.target - GNOME X11 Session (session: gnome-flashback-metacity).
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644308-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Stopping gnome-session-x11@gnome-flashback-metacity.target - GNOME X11 Session (session: gnome-flashback-metacity)...
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644319-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Stopped target gnome-session@gnome-flashback-metacity.target - GNOME Session (session: gnome-flashback-metacity).
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644337-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Stopping gnome-session@gnome-flashback-metacity.target - GNOME Session (session: gnome-flashback-metacity)...
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644349-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Reached target gnome-session@gnome-flashback-metacity.target - GNOME Session (session: gnome-flashback-metacity).
2024-11-13T17:00:27.644365-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Reached target gnome-session-x11@gnome-flashback-metacity.target - GNOME X11 Session (session: gnome-flashback-metacity).
2024-11-13T17:00:27.655999-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Starting gnome-flashback.service - GNOME Flashback...
2024-11-13T17:00:27.657713-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Started gnome-session-failed.service - GNOME Session Failed lockdown screen (user).
2024-11-13T17:00:27.657768-05:00 taco systemd[835191]: Reached target gnome-session-failed.target - GNOME Session Failed.
2024-11-13T17:00:27.841427-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Property 'libinput Accel Profiles Available' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
2024-11-13T17:00:27.841776-05:00 taco gnome-flashback[1705499]: Property 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default' for device 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G402' returned 3 items, expected 2
2024-11-13T17:00:27.873351-05:00 taco dbus-daemon[1517293]: [session uid=1000 pid=1517293] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested by ':1.346' (uid=1000 pid=1705514 comm="ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable" label="unconfined")


Here's an example of what sometimes happen. as you can see it seems it's trying to use wayland.
2024-11-06T13:46:40.994073-05:00 taco dbus-daemon[757828]: [session uid=1000 pid=757828] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome'
2024-11-06T13:46:40.994225-05:00 taco systemd[3946]: Started xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service - Portal service (GNOME implementation).
2024-11-06T13:46:41.000304-05:00 taco rtkit-daemon[3026]: Supervising 15 threads of 9 processes of 2 users.
2024-11-06T13:46:41.000496-05:00 taco rtkit-daemon[3026]: message repeated 2 times: [ Supervising 15 threads of 9 processes of 2 users.]
2024-11-06T13:46:41.000971-05:00 taco dbus-daemon[757828]: [session uid=1000 pid=757828] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.servic
e' requested by ':1.103' (uid=1000 pid=759485 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal" label="unconfined")
2024-11-06T13:46:41.008149-05:00 taco systemd[3946]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
2024-11-06T13:46:41.100988-05:00 taco dbus-daemon[757828]: [session uid=1000 pid=757828] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk'
2024-11-06T13:46:41.101046-05:00 taco systemd[3946]: Started xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation).
2024-11-06T13:46:41.107663-05:00 taco dbus-daemon[757828]: [session uid=1000 pid=757828] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop'
2024-11-06T13:46:41.107702-05:00 taco systemd[3946]: Started xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service.
2024-11-06T13:46:41.152135-05:00 taco dbus-daemon[757828]: [session uid=1000 pid=757828] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
2024-11-06T13:46:41.152200-05:00 taco systemd[3946]: Started gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server.
2024-11-06T13:46:41.227169-05:00 taco systemd[3946]: Started vte-spawn-07bcab0f-d26f-4f50-813e-501aa8f0491d.scope - VTE child process 759533 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 759480.
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241177-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241219-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraAccessEnable
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241235-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraAccessDisable
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241248-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86CameraAccessToggle
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241290-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NextElement
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241303-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86PreviousElement
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241315-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86AutopilotEngageToggle
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241328-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86MarkWaypoint
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241340-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86Sos
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241352-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NavChart
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241365-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86FishingChart
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241378-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86SingleRangeRadar
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241390-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86DualRangeRadar
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241407-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86RadarOverlay
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241419-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86TraditionalSonar
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241431-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86ClearvuSonar
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241443-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86SidevuSonar
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241455-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: > Warning:          Could not resolve keysym XF86NavInfo
2024-11-06T13:46:41.241752-05:00 taco /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[759544]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
2024-11-06T13:46:45.663580-05:00 taco gnome-shell[757960]: Connection to xwayland lost
2024-11-06T13:46:45.663787-05:00 taco gnome-shell[757960]: Xwayland terminated, exiting since it was mandatory
2024-11-06T13:46:45.663876-05:00 taco gnome-shell[757960]: (../src/core/meta-context.c:542):meta_context_terminate: runtime check failed: (g_main_loop_is_running (priv->main_loop))
2024-11-06T13:46:45.663967-05:00 taco gnome-shell[757960]: JS ERROR: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Xwayland exited unexpectedly#012@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21:20
2024-11-06T13:46:45.664385-05:00 taco gnome-shell[757960]: Execution of main.js threw exception: Module resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js threw an exception
2024-11-06T13:46:45.679714-05:00 taco systemd[1]: session-c4.scope: Deactivated successfully.
2024-11-06T13:46:45.679908-05:00 taco systemd[1]: session-c4.scope: Consumed 2.468s CPU time.
2024-11-06T13:46:45.770945-05:00 taco gdm3: Gdm: Child process -757883 was already dead.
2024-11-06T13:46:55.729344-05:00 taco systemd[1]: Stopping user@120.service - User Manager for UID 120...
2024-11-06T13:46:55.729747-05:00 taco systemd[757866]: Activating special unit exit.target...
2024-11-06T13:46:55.729785-05:00 taco systemd[757866]: Stopped target default.target - Main User Target.
2024-11-06T13:46:55.730073-05:00 taco systemd[757866]: Stopping dbus.service - D-Bus User Message Bus...


The thing is when I do it doesn't seem like wayland
> echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
> echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

I did add the following to /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false

but it still happens. X is for sure running too
> ps aux | grep X
billy      1706542  3.0  0.4 1540572 139600 tty2   Sl+  17:00   1:02 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -background none -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3


Does anybody have any idea how I can fix this? The issue is mainly that my entire DE crashes and I have to login again. Losing any and all open windows.
I am using an AMD 7900GRE gpu

Does it also crash if you use default Ubuntu session? Try to report bug - ubuntu-bug gnome-flashback (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)
